# Should I make the Jump from Windows 8

Tags: 13.10, windows-8, users, steam

I feel like trying something new. I'm on Windows 8 right now and I use it simply for using the internet, gaming, and homework. I'm mostly scared of compatibility issues.
Do you think I would enjoy the switch?

p.s I'm getting into programming with basic languages like javascript will it be easier in any way?

Comment: there is no way anyone here can answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Ubuntu ISO and make a bootable USB or CD and use the Try it out function.

If you find you like Ubuntu dual-boot it alongside Windows for a while, and then, and only then, if you think Ubuntu is for you, delete your windows partition and your initiation to the darkside will be completed.

Ubuntu has great programs available in the software center for all sorts of coding and programming, and pretty much everything else. Although it is VASTLY different to windows so don't make the jump if your afraid of learning.

Gaming is getting easier and easier with Valves support and the almighty Steam if that means anything to you.

All in all, the only person who can tell you if you like Ubuntu or not is you, so try it out.